# Old Bundler gem version being used by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We recently moved to Rails 4. I have run 'bundle update' (after removing the Gemfile.lock files). I have run into the below problem:

`rails s`

stops giving the following error message:

`Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":`

`In Gemfile:`
    `ryp depends on`
      `bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)`

`Current Bundler version:`
    **`bundler (1.0.15)`**

But I have checked that the bundler version is 1.3.5 as follows:

`bundle version`

**`Bundler version 1.3.5`**

And tried to uninstall **1.0.15 version** as follows:

`gem uninstall bundler --version 1.0.15`

which results in this message:

`INFO:  gem "bundler" is not installed`

How can I fix the above problem ?

Comment: Does `bundle exec rails s` work?

Comment: @Beerlington - yes, "bundle exec rails s"  works.

Comment: Are you using any ruby version managers such as rvm, rbenv, or chruby?

Comment: @carolclarinet - Yes, I am using rvm  (rvm use 1.9.3-p392)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using gemsets, something that's worked for me in the past is uninstalling the version of bundler that is in your global gemset:

```
rvm gemset use global
gem uninstall bundler
```

Then switch back to whatever gemset your project uses.